# Compute offset in file given line and column numbers

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a built-in function in elisp that given a filename, line number and column number will return the character offset into the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in?  Not that I know of.  Is this what you want?

```
(defun foo (file line column &optional msgp)
  "..."
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "File: ") 
                     (read-number    "Line: ")
                     (read-number    "Columnn: ")
                     t))
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
    (goto-line line)
    (forward-char column)
    (when msgp (message "Char in file: %d" (point)))
    (point)))
```

This doesn't bother to handle whether there are enough lines or columns on the chosen line, but you can take care of that.